# CSS: Table & TD with no border

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Using angularjs with bootstrap 3 here.

I am trying to create dynamic rows when user clicks button. I have wrapped this inside a table and using ng-repeat.

When the second row is added it creates a separation b/w the two.

Below is my code:

```
<table class="table table-borderless">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="m in options">

      <tr>
        <td>{{m.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{m.Country}}</td>
        <td>
          <a class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="Remove($index)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Name" required />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Country" required />
        </td>
        <td>
          <a class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="Add()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

I also created a demo at: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lyxbhosv/

Any inputs on how to remove the line or border in between two TD

Comment: Border between rows? In bootsrap it's default behavior to make border between rows: `.table>tbody>tr>td {border-top: 1px solid #ddd;}` but you can `.table>tbody>tr>td {border-top: none;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you're asking but via your example there is a double border whenever another row is added. To remove the double border and keep it a single just modify your code with the following:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="m in options" style="border: none;">
```

If you can explain further that would be great!

Comment: Thanks,  that was it. I was talking about the horizontal line that appears between 2 rows which seem to be go away with your code.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm examining your code you have already awarded the answer. But here I'm coming up with what I have learned from your code and this answer:

`<tbody ng-repeat="m in options" style="border: none;">` This will create lots of Repeatable `' in your code.

But if you placed your code 'ng-repeat="m in options"' to the child `<tr>' tag it will repeat the` ` each time. and it will not create any repeatable border any more.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="m in options">
```

So the choice is yours!